# SSRS Dynamic Width for Body of Report

Tags: dynamic, ssrs-2017

I have a report that currently has a table with 10 columns. I have visibility rules set on the last 5 columns to hide in some scenarios. When I hide those columns there is a large amount of white space on the right side of the report. I do not want this, i want the table to fill out the page. Ideally SSRS would have the capability to have the page width be dynamic and move with the width of the table, but that does not appear to be the case.

I tried creating two tables, one with 10 columns and one with 5 and set the visibility rules on the table, but that created the same problem, a lot of white space on the right side when the table with 5 columns was selected, because the width of the page was set for the 10 column table.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a workaround or how to fix this issue? I know I could create two reports, but I'm hoping to avoid that option.